# Amount of wood needed to cook rice

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, temperature, efficient-energy-use

$\def\¿{\:\mathrm}$I am trying to estimate the amount of wood fuel used by household using 3 stone stoves to cook rice. These stoves have a thermal efficiency of 10%.

I first calculated the energy needed to get the rice to boiling point, via $Q = mc\Delta T$. The specific heat of rice is $0.0018 \¿{MJ/kgK}$ and I have taken $\Delta T$ to be $70$. So, to heat $500 \¿{grams}$ of rice, I need $1*0.0018*70 = 0.126 \¿{MJ}$.

The Net Calorific Value of wood is $15.6 \¿{MJ/kg}$, so I reasoned that, at an efficiency of 10%, the amount of wood needed is $(0.126/15.6) / 0.1 = 0.081\¿{ kg} = 80\¿{ grams}$.

So, it seems as though I need only $80$ grams of wood to heat $1 \¿{kg}$ of rice from $30$ to $100$ degree celcius. Is this true? Do I only require such little wood to boil rice?

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: Aren't you forgetting something rather important? Have you cooked rice before? You cook rice in water, and you cook it until the water boils off. Also, you lose heat to the air; Not all of it ends up in the rice, nor will all the wood present burn completely. You are going to need to know the weight ratio of uncooked dry rice to cooked wet rice to figure out how much water should remain behind. You add enough water  for the rice to absorb plus extra water in an amount so that by the time it finishes boiling away to moderate temperature, the rice is cooked

Comment: Not only does not all the heat go into the rice, the rice and water itself constantly loses heat to the air which needs to be replenished.